# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -2

Tags: java, string

There is `String` named `s11` and I want to remove double quotes from the string.
The `s11` string contains `4b22a0f8-9047-4fd9-8330-d6fa7c85e90c`.
I used the following code:

```
String s12=s11.substring(1,s11.length()-1);
System.out.println(s12);
```

I got the following error:

> java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range:
>
> -2

Comment: what is the output of s11.length() ?

Comment: "*The s11 string contains `"4b22a0f8-9047-4fd9-8330-d6fa7c85e90c"`*" if exception comes from `s11.substring(1,s11.length()-1);` line then it doesn't contain what you claim. I actually doubt that this exception is related to code you posted because index `-2` can't be achieved here (length() is never negative so `nonNegativeValue - 1` can't never result with `-2`). Post code which will let us reproduce your problem. Also post stacktrace.

Comment: To remove double quotes you can you String s12=s11.replace("\"", ""); bytheway

Comment: Agree with @Pshemo. s11 is most probably empty, so `s11.length() - 1` is `-1` and since substring is exclusive for the upper bound, you get an error with an indenx of `-2`.

Comment: The LEngth of s11 returned 38. I have used similar length of string under the same class but only this string s11 gives error. I have declared and printed in a proper way.

Comment: This question has got absolutely nothing to do with selenium-webdriver.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to remove quotes, try:

```
String s12=s11.replaceAll("\"","");
```

That doesnt break on empty strings and does what you want

Answer (score 0):

```
String s11 = "4b22a0f8-9047-4fd9-8330-d6fa7c85e90c";
String s12=s11.substring(1,s11.length()-1);
System.out.println(s12);
```

works fine for me with the output

```
b22a0f8-9047-4fd9-8330-d6fa7c85e90
```